# How to serialize buttons in android?

Tags: android, button, serialization, save

I allow user to create buttons dynamically, so I need to save them for displaying next time when application will be run. What is the easiest way to do it?

P.S: Buttons in android not serializable

Comment: Just serialize the meta data about the button e.g. text, size color or whatever you allow the users to do when creating it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the easiest way to do it?

Step #1: Collect the data from the user that you are then using to "create buttons dynamically"

Step #2: Save that data in a database, `SharedPreferences`, or some other form of file

Step #3: Load that data as needed in the future

Whether you use a database, `SharedPreferences`, or some other form of file will depend a lot upon what else is in your app, the nature of the data that you are collecting, how many buttons there are, etc.